# Anchor tag's onclick isn't executing a simple jQuery function in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm following an online jQuery tutorial, and I'm unable to get this markup to work in jsfiddle:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ShowBox()
{
        $("#divTestArea1").fadeIn();
}
</script>
</head>

<div id="divTestArea1" style="padding: 50px; background-color: #89BC38; text-align: center; display: none;">
        <b>Hello, world!</b>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowBox();">Show box</a>

</html>
```

Here's the jsfiddle version that isn't working: [fadeIn test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidCondit/H72NG/)

The onclick event should fire when the hyperlink is clicked, which should call the ShowBox function. ShowBox should "fadeIn()" the display:none div, id #divTestArea1. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wrapping it like this its working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowBox()
{
        $("#divTestArea1").fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TFyLu/)

Comment: Thanks, Ehsan! BTW, I saw your WPF app on your blog. It looks fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle isn't working because you have the option that says how to load your javascript library incorrectly. Set it to "No wrap - in " so that your function will be defined before the html is loaded.

You won't have to change any of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/H72NG/5/

```
function ShowBox()
{
        $("#divTestArea1").fadeIn();
}
```