# Uncaught Refercence Error: getName is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Inspect element in Chrome keeps telling me that getName is not defined? Here is where getName is called on in the html:

```
<a id="nameGet" onclick="getName();" style="color: blue; white-space: nowrap;font-size: small; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 55px;"><u>Edit Profile</u></a>
```

And this is where I defined (so I believe) getName. This is in the

```
function getName () {
   name = prompt("Full Name: ");
   document.getElementById("pname").innerHTML = name;
   document.getElementById("nameGet").style.fontSize = "small";
   document.getElementById("postName1").innerHTML = name;
   document.getElementById("postName1").style.textDecoration = "bold";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this in a `<script></script>` block or in a separate file?

Comment: Can you show the full markup of the script block? Is it in the head or the body?

Comment: This type of error often means there is something wrong with your code before the function getName is reached.  JavaScript execution is terminated so it doesn't know that that function exists.

Comment: i tried it and i'm getting an error only on document.getElementById("pname").innerHTML = name; 
that is, the function is getting called correctly and then erroring later.

Comment: We need the full code to find out where the error is.  And of course that didn't work ^ do you have an element with the id "pname"?

Comment: actually, for our purposes it did work - it errored once it was in the function, which means the function is getting properly called.  OP, please post your code.

Comment: I created a [Reproducible Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/ykhn7aaq/) and a version that uses onclick instead, which works [Alternative Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/ykhn7aaq/1/)

Comment: @BaylorNorris, Did you test your code in JSFiddle?

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? (See [this article](http://wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/) to see how to access the browser console in your browser.)

Comment: The problem isn't reproducible in JSFiddle if you change the options to load the JS in head instead of onLoad: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/ykhn7aaq/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lng9j9nq/ (Oops - No)

Here is a fiddle with wrapped HTML : http://jsfiddle.net/Lng9j9nq/1/ (Works)

And here is a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJEYEo (Works)

So, the fiddle **must** be facing some issues. Then I pasted the following function in the console:

```
function getName() {
  name = prompt("Full Name: ");
  document.getElementById("pname").innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById("nameGet").style.fontSize = "small";
  document.getElementById("postName1").innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById("postName1").style.textDecoration = "bold";
}
```

Then, I called the function from console `getName()`. It works with **console**. So, it's not your code but JSFiddle. **Your Code works.**

Comment: After some research, it seems that the JSFiddle options are the culprit.  You have to change it to "No Wrap - in <head>" and then all works fine.  Located that answer here: [Anchor tag's onclick isn't executing a simple jQuery function in jsfiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766686/anchor-tags-onclick-isnt-executing-a-simple-jquery-function-in-jsfiddle)